# Should I get keep vsftp service running?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd which is an FTP server on Linux. Should I keep the service running or stop it after use?

```
service vsftpd status
```

shows that service is active.

Comment: It's a bit like asking if you should lock your door when you leave. It depends on how long you will be away and how much you trust your door and your neighbourhood.